# Hibernate JPA trava

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Quando executa o persistencia para cirar as tabelas no banco o netbeans trava as saidas neste item

> out 26, 2016 3:11:05 PM org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect  INFO:
>   HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect

Não consigo descobir qual é o problema!

Classe

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package br.com.app.entidades;

import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;

/**
 *
 * @author Wagner
 */
@Entity
public class Mesa implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    private String descricao;

    public Mesa() {
    }



    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getDescricao() {
        return descricao;
    }

    public void setDescricao(String descricao) {
        this.descricao = descricao;
    }



    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 0;
        hash += (id != null ? id.hashCode() : 0);
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object object) {
        // TODO: Warning - this method won't work in the case the id fields are not set
        if (!(object instanceof Mesa)) {
            return false;
        }
        Mesa other = (Mesa) object;
        if ((this.id == null && other.id != null) || (this.id != null && !this.id.equals(other.id))) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "br.com.app.entidades.Mesa[ id=" + id + " ]";
    }

}
```

Persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="AppTestePU" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <class>br.com.app.entidades.Mesa</class>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    <properties>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/teste2?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="root"/>
      <property name="hibernate.cache.provider_class" value="org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action" value="create"/>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Comment: Amigo, sem ver o seu código, os seus beans de entidade, os relacionamentos entre tabelas, o seu `persistence.xml` ou similar, sem saber quais são as suas classes, qual a versão do hibernate, quais as bibliotecas, fica muito difícil de te ajudar, não acha? Por favor, providencie mais informações para que alguém que vá responder a pergunta tenha algo no que se embasar.

Comment: Mas, independente disso, essa mensagem **não se trata de um erro**. Ela apenas está dizendo que o Hibernate está usando o MySQL. Isso daí trata-se de uma mensagem normal e esperada. Se ocorre algum travamento ou a aplicação não funciona, essa mensagem não tem relação com o problema.

Comment: Obrigado! vou adicionar as informações

Comment: Não...ainda trava!

Comment: Ajuste o log do hibernate para `DEBUG` e veja se aparece mais informações úteis para descobrir a causa do problema.

Comment: ok...vou tentar fazer isto! obrigado

Comment: Se estiver usando o Hibernate que vem no NetBeans 8.0.2 ele trava mesmo ( http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/184968/hibernate-funciona-ok-mas-n%c3%a3o-termina-o-processo ). Tem até como não travar fazendo um macetinho que responderam aí nesse tópico, mas em hipótese alguma baixe outro NetBeans só por causa disso, melhor baixar a versão mais nova do Hibernate... ^_^! Se tiver dúvidas de como você pode linkar os jars do Hibernate no seu projeto, faça uma pergunta aqui que muita gente sabe responder isso. Faço isso de forma automática fuçando sempre que preciso e é bem fácil de resolver.