# Hibernate funciona OK, mas não termina o processo

Tags: java, hibernate

Não sei se isso é normal, mas o Hibernate inicia o processo, insere o objeto no banco, mas o processo java dele fica aberto.

**O que tenho que fazer para que esse processo termine automaticamente após a inserção?**

Segue um código exemplificando o problema:

TesteHibernate.java

```
package testehibernate;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

public class TesteHibernate
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Configuration configuration = new Configuration().configure();

        StandardServiceRegistryBuilder builder = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(configuration.getProperties());

        SessionFactory factory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(builder.build());
        Session session = factory.openSession();

        Teste teste = new Teste();
        teste.setNome("Alexandre");
        teste.setEmail("alexandre@email.com");

        session.beginTransaction();
        session.save(teste);
        session.getTransaction().commit();    

        session.close();
        factory.close(); // Não muda nada, o processo continua sem encerrar
    }

}
```

Teste.java

```
package testehibernate;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class Teste
{
    @Id
    private int id;
    private String nome;
    private String email;

    public int getId()
    {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id)
    {
        this.id = id;
    }    

    public String getNome()
    {
        return nome;
    }

    public void setNome(String nome)
    {
        this.nome = nome;
    }

    public String getEmail()
    {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email)
    {
        this.email = email;
    }

}
```

Tabela teste:

```
CREATE TABLE `teste` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `nome` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(255) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

ALTER TABLE `teste`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);
TO_INCREMENT for table `teste`

ALTER TABLE `teste`
  MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=14;
```

hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>

   <session-factory>
        <!-- Database connection settings -->
        <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/testdb</property>
        <property name="connection.username">root</property>
        <property name="connection.password"></property>

        <!-- JDBC connection pool (use the built-in) -->
        <property name="connection.pool_size">1</property>

        <!-- SQL dialect -->
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>

        <!-- Echo all executed SQL to stdout -->
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>

        <!-- Mapping files -->
        <mapping class="testehibernate.Teste"/>
    </session-factory>

</hibernate-configuration>
```

**Segue código modificado e funcionando com a dica do Murilo para fechar o registry:**

```
package testehibernate;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;
import org.hibernate.service.ServiceRegistry;

public class TesteHibernate
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Configuration configuration = new Configuration().configure();

        ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(configuration.getProperties()).build();

        SessionFactory factory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
        Session session = factory.openSession();

        Teste teste = new Teste();
        teste.setNome("Alfredo");
        teste.setEmail("alfredo@email.com");

        session.beginTransaction();
        session.save(teste);
        session.getTransaction().commit();    

        session.close();
        factory.close();

        StandardServiceRegistryBuilder.destroy(serviceRegistry);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Já tentou fechar o service registry, assim?

```
package testehibernate;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.service.ServiceRegistry;
import org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

public class TesteHibernate
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Configuration configuration = new Configuration().configure();

        ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(configuration.getProperties()).build();

        SessionFactory factory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
        Session session = factory.openSession();

        Teste teste = new Teste();
        teste.setNome("Alexandre");
        teste.setEmail("alexandre@email.com");

        session.beginTransaction();
        session.save(teste);
        session.getTransaction().commit();    

        session.close();
        factory.close();

        StandardServiceRegistryBuilder.destroy(serviceRegistry);
    }

}
```

Comment: Resolveu.
Pra sua resposta ficar perfeita, apenas inclua o  import org.hibernate.service.ServiceRegistry;
Grande abraço. :)

Comment: Feito! Obrigado! Abraço!

Answer (score 3):

Você precisa fechar a sua `SessionFactory` utilizando o método `close`assim:

```
package testehibernate;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

public class TesteHibernate {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Configuration configuration = new Configuration().configure();

        StandardServiceRegistryBuilder builder = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(configuration.getProperties());

        SessionFactory factory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(builder.build());
        Session session = factory.openSession();

        Teste teste = new Teste();
        teste.setNome("Alexandre");
        teste.setEmail("alexandre@email.com");

        session.beginTransaction();
        session.save(teste);
        session.getTransaction().commit();    

        session.close();
        factory.close();                //<<<----Fechando a SessionFactory
    }

}
```

#### Edit:

Isso é um *bug* específico da versão que você está utilizando (versão 4.3.0.Final) causado pelo *connection pool* do Hibernate, como pode ser visto [aqui](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-8896). Como já foram lançadas diversas novas versões, o ideal seria você atualizar para uma versão onde o *bug* tenha sida corrigido.

Caso você não possa fazer isso, utilize algum outro *connection pool* já que o connection pool do hibernate não é para ser utilizado em produção ou adicione a seguinte linha ao fim do seu código:

```
StandardServiceRegistryBuilder.destroy(builder);
```

Comment: Felipe,  em casa eu tinha feito fechado a factory tb mas não foi. Dei +1 pela vontade e tb pq eu não tô na frente do computador pra testar de novo. Mas se vc puder testar e ver se isso mesmo resolve ajudaria muito.  Quando chegar em casa vou ver isso de novo.  Se  funcionar aceito como resposta.  Mas a princípio embora não esteja na pergunta eu tinha tentado antes fechando factory tb e deu no mesmo.

Comment: @AntonioAlexandre Eu testei e funcionou normalmente. Qual versão do Hibernate você está utilizando?

Comment: só terei como ver a versão agora na segunda quando chegar em casa.  Quando se fala em funcionar funcionar,  bem...  funciona. A questão é que algo no Hibernate faz com que ele continue rodando e não deixa o processo encerrar naturalmente. Esse é o problema.

Comment: Felipe, a versão do Hibernate que estou usando no teste é a 4.3. Nessa versão apenas fechando a factory não libera o processo após a execução. Vou testar com outras versões. A pergunta ainda está em aberto pra quem tiver outras idéias.

Comment: @AntonioAlexandre Isso é um bug da versão que você está utilizando, editei minha resposta com mais detalhes.

Comment: Obrigado por clarificar Felipe! Vou baixar a versão mais nova e basear meu desenvolvimento nela.

Answer (score -2):

Adicione no final:

```
 HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().close();
```

Comment: No final de qual função? Em qual linha exatamente? Seja mais claro para ajudar futuras pessoas com a mesma dúvida.